How to solve a paths optimization problem in node-labeled and weighted graphs
I am having trouble finding a way to optimize this problem in Python. Even if it is not exact, I am trying some heuristics.
Let $G = (V,\mathbf{L}, E,\mathbf{W})$ be a graph where $V$ is the set of vertices, $\mathbf{L}$ is the vector with the values of the labels of the nodes, $E$ is the set of edges (the graph is undirected), and $\mathbf{W}$ is the matrix with edge weights. Now I have $T \in \mathbb{N}$ traveling salesmen and I have to assign $T$ paths whose total weight sum for each path is less than the same arbitrary parameter $\lambda \geq 0$. I also want to maximize profit over all $T$ paths, which is the sum of the labels of the nodes in the paths.
Here, the difference with the regular traveling salesman problem is that the edge weights are not subtracted from the node-profit and are independent of them.
I was trying a heuristic where I would try to optimize the problem for one path only, and then remove the visited nodes (and adjacent edges) and optimize the problem for the second path, and so on. The problem is I can't find a way to optimize the problem with one path even.
I am happy with a way to approximate it too since I believe any exact solution might not be computable for large graphs in a "decent" amount of time.
Thank you for the help I don't know how to start tackling this problem any other way.

I think at least you can do some greedy way. Starting from a node $v$ with the highest profit $L(v)$, and then greedily choosing the next node $u$, e.g., by the ratio $L(u) / W(u, v)$, until reaching the budget $\lambda$.

My problem is for example (a very artificial worst-case scenario one), what if the node with value $L^* = \mathrm{max}(L_i)i$ is connected only to nodes with values of $0$ via edges all with values $W{i,j} > \lambda$. In this case, we start the greedy search and stop immediately at the first node. I was thinking on running the algorithm several times on random starting nodes and pick from there. Or maybe try to get an approximation of the connectedness of each node and see how much is the sum of $L_i$ surrounding said node and increase depth as in BFS
